Why NLL does not work at function boundaries?
The Rust borrow checker guarantees that if a value is mutably borrowed, it should not be borrowed (mutably or not) a second time until the lifetime of the first borrow ends.
NLL (non-lexical lifetime) is a new Rust feature that makes the lifetime of a borrow end when it's not used anymore in the lexical scope, rather than live until the borrow effectively exits the lexical scope. I see this feature working when I need to manipulate a borrowed structure (for example, calling mutating methods on values inside it), but it seems to not work when I call a function that seemingly does a second borrow on the structure itself. NLL should be able to automatically end a borrow when it sees that it's not used anymore in the scope, so that a second (mutable) borrow can happen in that scope without triggering error.
Let's see how my code looks like:
fn handle_menu_transition(&mut self, transition: MenuTransition) {
    match transition {
        MenuTransition::Quit => self.quitting = true,
        MenuTransition::StartGame => self.state = ClientState::Playing(Game::default()),
        _ => {}
    }
}

fn update(&mut self) -> bool {
    let now = std::time::Instant::now();
    let delta_time = now - self.last_update;
    self.last_update = now;

    match &mut self.state {
        ClientState::MainMenu(menu) => { 
            self.handle_menu_transition(menu.update(delta_time));
            true
        }
        ClientState::Playing(game) => {
            self.render()
        }
        ClientState::PauseMenu(menu, game) => {
            self.handle_menu_transition(menu.update(delta_time));
            self.render()
        }
    }
}

For additional informations, self.render is a non-mutating method, MenuTransition is an enum that derives Copy/Clone, and menu.update is a mutating method on my Menu structure, so the self.state enum needs to be borrowed mutably (because Menu is contained inside the state).
I don't understand why the NLL feature cannot see that after each call to handle_menu_transition, the first borrow (in the match clause) is not used anymore, so it's possible to drop it here so that the second borrow (at call of handle_menu_transition) can happen. If I remove the handle_menu_transition method altogether from my code and copy-paste the code inside it at the call site, or if I save the MenuTransition resulting from menu.update() in a separate variable before calling handle_menu_transition, the borrow checker does not complain anymore. Do you know why it is so ?

"NLL is a new Rust feature that ..." - I don't think something introduced six years ago can really be considered "new".

@kmdreko Well, I consider it new because it's enabled by default since compiler v1.63 which is only 2 years old

The 1.63 change was just enabling it for Rust crates using the 2015 edition (and the main motivation for that was to lighten the maintenance burden by completely removing the old borrow checker).
